# Port Connection with Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, rubygems

Can anyone help me with this ruby script right, I am trying to connect using ruby script
What I tried:

```
Ruby version: ruby 2.7.3p183 (2021-04-05 revision 6847ee089d) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

*require 'socket'
socket = TCPSocket 172.16.5.10 7707*
```

> error :rbexp.rb:3: unexpected fraction part after numeric literal
> ...ket = TCPSocket.new 172.16.5.10, 7707

Answer (score 0):

About your error `unexpected fraction part after numeric literal`: ruby parse 172.16.5.10 as numeric literal - use String "172.16.5.10".

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way of solving your issue is as follows:

```rb
require 'socket'

socket = TCPSocket.new "172.16.5.10", 7707

while line = socket.gets
  puts line
end

socket.close
puts "Bye!"
```